# Vuetify - How to generate dynamic values in data-tables?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm processing JSON data and format it with Vuetify's [Data Tables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/).

The documentation says to define table `headers` in the following manner:

```js
import data from './data.json'

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            cities_data: data,
            headers: [
                { text: 'City', sortable: true, value: 'city' },  // 'city', 'citizens', etc., are JSON keys
                { text: '#Citizens', sortable: true, value: 'citizens' },
                { text: '#Schools', sortable: true, value: 'schools' },
                { text: 'Schools per Citizen', value: this.countSchoolsPerCitizen }
            ]
(...)
```

In `computed` methods I tried this:

```js
computed: {
    countSchoolsPerCitizen() {
        return this.schools / this.citizens
    }
}
```

...and since I'm here, you know that it doesn't work :-)

Console doesn't give any hints, neither errors nor warnings are displayed; simply there are just empty values displayed below non-empty header title.

Any ideas how to proceed with it?

Comment: where is your items?  is that value (`countSchoolsPerCitizen`) repeated in all column cells?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim: just added references to the items and data source, please take a look at the code.

Comment: is that value (countSchoolsPerCitizen) repeated in all column cells?

Comment: Can you post the template so we can see how data is used?

Comment: have you confirmed that `this.schools / this.citizens` at least returns a reasonable value? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cities_data` which should be a computed property with additional column called `countSchoolsPerCitizen`:

```
computed: {
    cities_data(){
     return data.map(d=>{
       d.countSchoolsPerCitizen = d.schools / d.citizens;
       return d;   
       })
   }
}
```

**`headers`** data property should be like :

```
  headers: [
                { text: 'City', sortable: true, value: 'city' },  // 'city', 'citizens', etc., are JSON keys
                { text: '#Citizens', sortable: true, value: 'citizens' },
                { text: '#Schools', sortable: true, value: 'schools' },
                { text: 'Schools per Citizen', value: 'countSchoolsPerCitizen' }
                   //reference that additional column here -----^                                      
            ]
```